# Python Pandas DataFrames: Compare rows two by two recusively.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, row

I would like to compare the rows from the table two by two and retain only the similar matches.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('a', [0,1,1,0]), ('b', [0,0,1,1]),('c',[1,0,0,1]), ('d',[1,0,1,0])], orient='index', columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df

   A  B  C  D
a  0  1  1  0
b  0  0  1  1
c  1  0  0  1
d  1  0  1  0
```

And transform in this table:

```
     A  B  C  D
a/b  0  0  1  0
a/c  0  0  0  0
a/d  0  0  1  0
a/d  0  0  0  0
b/c  0  0  0  1
b/d  0  0  1  0
c/d  1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use itertools to iterate over all combinations of rows to make a new set of items, like this:

```
import itertools
new_items = [('{}/{}'.format(i1, i2), r1 * r2) 
                for (i1, r1), (i2, r2) in itertools.combinations(df.iterrows(), 2)]
transformed = pd.DataFrame.from_items(new_items, orient='index', columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Answer (score 3):

***explanation***

- The first thing to do is generate a mechanism for iterating through every combination.  I chose `np.triu_indices`.  This is numpy's way to give me access to the upper triangle of a square matrix.  @Michael accomplishes this using `itertools.combinations`.
- Then next thing to take care of is formatting the index.  @Michael and I both use `'{}/{}'.format`
- Finally, we need to put them all together.  I use `pd.concat`, @Michael uses `pd.DataFrame.ftom_items`
- I like @Michael's answer, I think, more than mine.  I'l likely use a combination of the two the next time I answer a similar question.
- I usually avoid pulling in `itertools` though I don't have a good reason for that.  Maybe I should :-)
- For a more broken down explanation, I encourage you to run this line by line and see what the components look like.

---

```
tups = zip(*np.triu_indices(df.shape[0], 1))
rnm = '{}/{}'.format
pd.concat(
    [df.iloc[i].mul(df.iloc[j]).rename(rnm(*df.index[[i, j]])) for i, j in tups],
     axis=1).T
```

[image]